# Excel VBA program fails on second run on statement CreateObject accessing DLL

Tags: excel, vba

I have some Excel 2010 VBA code running on a Windows 10 Pro computer.  The code creates an object for a DLL, and at the end of the program the object is set to nothing.  The code runs fine the first time, but if I run it again it crashes on the CreateObject line with the following error message:

Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)
Automation error
Unspecified error

It seems like the DLL object is not being released and that may be why it crashes when trying to create the object on a second run.  I found this web page which may be related:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/178510/excel-automation-fails-second-time-code-runs

Below is some sample code, and the line where it crashes is noted.  Any idea how to troubleshoot/fix this?  Could this problem be related to running Office 2010 on Windows 10?  The code worked on my prior Windows 7 computer.  By the way, I'm far from an expert in VBA so some of the terminology I'm using may be off.

```
Sub AddOverlayToPDF()
    Dim BasePath As String
    Dim InFolder As String
    Dim OutFolder As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim PDF, rslt

    BasePath = "C:\Users\macke\Desktop\"
    InFolder = BasePath & "Comm Charts - No Legend\"
    OutFolder = BasePath & "Comm Charts\"

    Set PDF = CreateObject("pdf.Meld") ' <-- *** THIS LINE FAILS ON SECOND RUN ***
    FileName = Dir(InFolder & "*")
    Do While Len(FileName) > 0
        Debug.Print FileName
        PDF.setRevOverlay
        PDF.setRepeat
        PDF.setOverlayPages ("9-11")

        PDF.setInFile "C:\Users\macke\Desktop\Legend Overlay.pdf"
        PDF.setInFile InFolder & FileName
        PDF.setOutFile OutFolder & FileName

        rslt = PDF.buildPDF
        If rslt < 0 And rslt <> -10 Then
            MsgBox ("Error " & rslt)
        End If
        PDF.setReset

        FileName = Dir
    Loop

    Set PDF = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if you add `PDF.Close` just before `Set PDF = Nothing`?

Comment: I added "PDF.Close" just before the "Set PDF = Nothing" line and got the following error message: Run-time error '9': Undefined subroutine &PDFMeld::untaint called at pdfmeld2.pl line 234.

Answer (score 0):

I have same error code -2147467259 (80004005) it turned out that the old Excel sheet my users were running is only compatible with Office x86.

I had made a new server with Office 2019 x64 - as soon as I reinstalled office to x86, the macros worked fine.

The ODBC instances was represented both in x32 and x64.
Check if you might have x64 versus x86 issues